# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following form

```
<%= form_for @contact, url: new_contact_path(@contact), remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<%= f.text_field :phone %>
<%= f.text_field :message %>
<%= f.submit 'Send' %>
```

Here is my controller contacts_controller.rb

```
def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        unless contact_params.nil?
            @contact = Contact.new contact_params
            @contact.save
        end
    end
```

When i submit the form getting error as

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

I tried this too

```
<%= form_for Contact.new, url: {controller: :contact,action: :create}, remote: true do |f| %>
```

But getting routing error

Here is my `rake routes`

```
contacts GET      /contacts(.:format)                    contacts#index
                   POST     /contacts(.:format)                    contacts#create
       new_contact GET      /contacts/new(.:format)                contacts#new
      edit_contact GET      /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)           contacts#edit
           contact GET      /contacts/:id(.:format)                contacts#show
                   PATCH    /contacts/:id(.:format)                contacts#update
                   PUT      /contacts/:id(.:format)                contacts#update
                   DELETE   /contacts/:id(.:format)                contacts#destroy
```

My route.rb has

`resources :contacts`

**Update-1**

```
private
    def contact_params
        params.require(:contact).permit(:customer_id,:post_id,:name,:email,:phone,:message)
    end
```

Comment: can you post your contact_params, most likely listed at the bottom of the controller.

Comment: @trh updated the question check it

Comment: One more thing to say form is in other view not in contacts view

Comment: What do you mean by: "Is in other view?" Where is it? It's supposed to be in views/contacts/new.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely getting the error because `@contact` isn't defined in your view. I'm not sure in which view you have the form or if you are rendering it, but try declaring `@contact` before your `unless` statement:

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new contact_params

  unless contact_params.nil?        
    @contact.save
  end
end
```

or something like that...either way, you have to define `@contact` in the controller action that corresponds to the view that contains your form, if that makes sense.